# How to find the quadrant of a dot product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Consider the vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{d}$ in the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmvP8.png)

Consider the list of dot products: dot(a,b) , dot(a,c) , dot(a,d) , dot(b,c) , dot(b,d) , dot(c,d)  (latex didn't work for this)

For each dot product, enter in positive if it's positive, negative if it's negative, and $0$ if it's equal to zero. Answer with the resulting list.

I tried
0   negative    negative    positive    negative    0

0   positive    negative    positive    negative    0

0   positive    negative    positive    positive    negative

but they r all wrong.

Comment: Basically,if the angle is acute, the dot product is positive; if right, the dot product is zero; if obtuse, the dot product is negative.  Looks like 0 + - + + 0 I guess you have to guess whether certain ones are really right angles, or merely close to it.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, for $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}>0\implies \cos\theta>0,$ then it is QI or QIV. For $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}<0\implies \cos\theta<0,$ then it is QII or QIII.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The dot product of two vectors $a,\, b\in\mathbb R^n$ is the same as
$$\langle a,\,b\rangle=\lVert a\rVert \lVert b\rVert \cos\varphi$$
where $\varphi$ is the angle enclosed by $a$ and $b$. Now, for which angles $\varphi$ is $\cos\varphi$ negative, for which positive?